# Double integral transform

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I found interesting for me integral's transform:
$$\int_a^\infty {\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\int_x^\infty{K_1(z)}}dzdx = \int_a^\infty{\sqrt{z^2-a^2}K_1(z)}dz$$
where $K_1$ is the modified Bessel functions of the second kind.

Can someone explain this transform? And how can I get transform for similar integral, like this:
$$\int_a^\infty {\int_x^\infty{K_1(z)}}dzdx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from interchanging the integrals and noting that $\int_a^{z}\frac x {\sqrt {x^{2}-a^{2}}} dx=\sqrt {z^{2}-a^{2}}$. Note that $a<x<z$ so $x$ ranges from $a$ to $z$.

The second one is $\int_a^{\infty} (z-a) K_1(z)dz$.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation!